# How can i click on Save button to save a downloaded file using protractor in IE

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor, ie

How can i click on Save button to save a downloaded file using protractor in IE.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This action changes the browser focus back to the OS and away from Protractor. I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Try to side-step this prompt by instructing the browser to download files to a specific location.
2. Configure the browser (in this case IE) to save the file automatically without prompting: [IE example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1345#issuecomment-361487527) . With Chrome it is possible to [set this as part of the browsers capabilities](https://medium.com/@hangmany/download-file-using-protractor-and-chrome-57-a79a1dab5014), maybe IE has something similar? (this would make the configuration more permanent)